# Decomposition of a unitary matrix

Tags: matrices

Is anyone aware of a decomposition of a unitary matrix into a product of a special unitary matrix and the rest?

Edit:

A unitary matrix is a matrix that satisfies

$\mathbf{U}\mathbf{U}^\dagger=1$

where $1$ is the unit matrix.
Now assume I have a matrix $\mathbf{U}$ with this property. Is there a known decomposition

$\mathbf{U} = \mathbf{D} \tilde{\mathbf{U}}$

with $\det(\tilde{\mathbf{U}})=1$ and $\mathbf{D}$ arbitrary?

Thanks ...

Comment: Take $\tilde{\mathbf{U}}$ to be the identity matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Sure: let $B$ be an arbitrary special unitary matrix. Then $U=(UB^{-1})B$ is such a decomposition. (For that matter, $U$ didn't even have to be unitary... we can factor all matrices this way!)

The problem is that this idea for factorization is too "squishy" because it allows $D$ to be *anything*. I'm guessing there are constraints on $D$ that make this question interesting.

Answer (score 0):

This question is somewhat vague, but what you may (or may not) be looking for might be something like this [referenced derivation](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1JunjKxazANM0RtbzhGTi1ZSVU).